# How to use index to get the value from the result of map function by Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try this:

```
def test(x):
    return x**2

a = map(test,[1,2,3])
```

If I get the value like this:

```
for i in a:
    print(a)
```

I will get `1,4,9` and this works perfectly.

But if I do this: `a[0]`. The error will be raised.

I know it is because the result of map function is map class:

```
type(map(test,[1,2,3])) == <class 'map'>
```

which is not subsciptable.

So how can I use the index to get the value of the result of map function?

**NOTE: This behavior is specific to python 3.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the `map` object into a `list` object:

```
a = list(map(test,[1,2,3]))
```

Then you can use list indices to access the individual elements.

Comment: This works perfectly. But if I do `a = map(test,[1,2,3])` and `a = list(a)`, `a` will be `[]`. Can you tell me why?

Comment: I think it has something to do with `map()` returning an iterator that gets consumed. Try printing `list(a)` 2 times & see how the list is only printed the first time.

Comment: @MarsLee I have written answer on this.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function in python 3 returns an iterator. Once you consume an iterator or it is exhausted, it won't yield you result any more.

```
a = map(lambda x: x**2, [1,2,3])
for i in a: print(a)
```

The result:

```
1
4
9
```

Now try,

```
a.__next__()
```

It will return you a `StopIteration` error, as the iterator is already exhausted.

To use index you can use `list` as suggested in the previous answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This is really clear. I just use out my vote today. I will give you an upvote tomorrow. Hope you don't mind.