# I want print Python map list element

Tags: python, list

I am trying to print a map list element but get the following errors:

```
inp(i-1)" this is error
```

and

```
inp[i-1]
```

My code:

```
num, a = map(int, input().split())
inp = map(int, input().split())
for i in range(1,num+1):
    if inp(i-1) < a:
        print(a)
```

How can I map the element output?

Comment: inp[i-1] also error

Comment: could you pls add that error too?

Comment: What are the inputs? How can we reproduce the error like that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use index to get the value from the result of map function by Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37110086/how-to-use-index-to-get-the-value-from-the-result-of-map-function-by-python-3)

Answer (score 2):

You should convert map obj to a list before indexing.

```
num, a = map(int, input().split())
inp = list(map(int, input().split()))
for i in range(1,num+1):
    if inp[i-1] < a:
        print(a)
```

Comment: hope you got the answer

Comment: Nevermind, i guess its just straightforward, even if the question is kinda bad written...

Comment: Nope, I am looking for clients.. :)

Comment: No. This is my hobby... I am not looking for clients via SO

Answer (score 1):

The first line should be changed to two lines:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
num = len(a)
```

---

Also, indexing is used with brackets `[]`, not parenthesis `()`, so try changing this line:

```
    if inp(i-1) < a:
```

To:

```
    if inp[i-1] < a:
```

So the full code would be:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
num = len(a)
inp = list(map(int, input().split()))
for i in range(1,num+1):
    if inp[i-1] < a:
        print(a)
```

Comment: wrong bro its giving TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len() this error

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ Edited mine, could you please retract your downvote?

Comment: So you're saying it makes sense to compare the integer `inp[i-1]` with the list `a`? And how do you know the first line should be changed like that?

Comment: I think it's more likely an input format [like this one](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/pairs/problem).

Comment: How do you guess that he wanted the length of the array printed when there isnt an input?